# Clarification on edit privilege information page

Tags: support, edits, community-wiki

From https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit:

> Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. Too many edits can also force a post into community wiki mode. Make your edits count.

I'm not sure what that second sentence means, could someone clarify this?

Is it too many edits to the same post? What happens if you edit the same post multiple times?

Or is it if you edit too many posts too often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What turns a post into *Community Wiki*?

> The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

From [What are Community Wiki Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

If you edit your question more than 10 times (it is not always exactly at the 10th time) it will be converted to community wiki automatically. Edits in the grace period don't count.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean this applies to editing others' posts now, too?

Comment: *The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.* That turns it into CW too.